# How to add a field to webform entry form

Tags: webforms

I am using webform to build a quiz site. Every quiz will be an "option" type where users will choose a, b or c.

I need to add to each page, an extra field to indicate which is the correct answer. I would like to have for each question entry form, a field where I can indicate which is the correct answer.

I can figure out the rest if I can have a way to have a text box appear for every question into which I can paste the correct answer.

Thanks for your help.